# IIS Express - internet access (not local network)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, web-deployment, iis-express

I developed a MVC web app on my computer , running on local IIS Express server. My problem is that now the client wants to see how the app looks and i need to transfer my app online. I don't want to buy any hosting yet, just to use my computer as a web server. My question is, how can i do this using iis express ?. I've searched on old google but only found how to make the app accessible for users on my network. Tutorials like [these](http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer) . I also want to mention that i am behind a router on which i have access to configure .

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your router to forward port 80 (or a custom port) to your hosting device. Therefore you first have to give your computer a static ip address (also on the router) and enable port forwarding from for example extern port 8181 to your static ip and intern port of your iis port.
Then from outside your clients can call your external ip-address (modem ip):8181 to visit your website.